# 3dsmax: Simulate Material Drag and Drop

Tags: .net, 3dsmax, maxscript

I'm trying to find out what kind of format 3dsmax uses for material drag and drop.

I tried to inspect the mime-type and data by dropping Materials from max into a pyQt window, but it didn't receive any drops from max.

Answer (score 0):

Max uses its own internal drag-and-drop system.  It can receive drags from explorer because it has a handler that reads the path of the item being dropped, but there is no way it can send data back out in a format that Windows would understand.

http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/15/ENU/3ds-Max-SDK-Programmer-Guide/cpp_ref/class_drag_and_drop_handler.html

What are you trying to achieve specifically?  If you want to handle a drop action within max, implement the class I linked, if you want to drag something out of max into an external program... well, that may be possible, but your going to have to do all the heavy lifting yourself.

Comment: I don't really need max to send anything back. What I want to do is start a material drag from my python application and have max accept it wherever it accepts materials.